# Sql error 110802 persisting and cant solve

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I was running adf along with Notebooks consistently and without error for a month.  This past Friday, out of the blue I started getting the below error on some tables in my pipeline.  The error also changes tables, and then after reran from fail will sometimes complete.  Our team has looked and cannot find what this might be referencing or how to solve.  Any input is appreciated!

Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 110802. Error Message: 110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Common.ExternalAccess.HdfsAccessException

Comment: Based on the message, it seems like access issues. Did the secrets you use to access the data change ?

Comment: ADF with Databricks Notebooks or Synapse Pipelines with Synapse Notebooks?  What is the source and target?

Comment: ADF with Databricks Notebooks.  We have a MSFT rep with the Synapse team reviewing they are thinking this goes back to product team.

Comment: Any update on this?